# How to run Cypress tests on circle-ci orb using Cypress-tags

Tags: cucumber, cypress, circleci, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to run a small test collection with Cypress using the [cucumber plugin](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor) and the official Circle-ci Orb.

I've been going through the documentation and I've got them running without issues locally. The script I'm using to run them locally is this one:

`"test:usa": "cypress-tags run --headless -b chrome -e TAGS='@usa'"`

*Note the ***cypress-tags*** command and the ***TAGS*** option.

For the CI I use the official [Circle-ci Orb](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/cypress-io/cypress#quick-start) and have a configuration like this:

```
- cypress/run:
          name: e2e tests
          executor: with-chrome
          record: true
          parallel: true
          parallelism: 2
          tags: 'on-pr'
          group: 2x-chrome
          ci-build-id: '${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}'
          requires:
            - org/deployment
```

As you can read, I want to raise 2 machines where I divide my feature files, setting the tag to 'on-pr' and grouping the run under '2x-chrome' using as well the ci-build-id.

The thing is that the official Orb uses the `cypress run` command which does not filter scenarios by their tags, so it is of no use here. My options were:

1. Using the ***command*** parameter in the orb to call the required script as I do locally:

`command: npm run test:usa`

My problem with this option is that the parallel configuration does not work as expected so I discarded it.

2. I tried to pass the ***TAGS parameter*** as an env var within the Circle-ci executor to see if the Orb was able to see it, but it was of no use as the Orb does not use `cypress-tags run` but `cypress run`.

```
environment:
      TAGS: '@usa'
```

At this point my question is, is there a workaround to this (using cypress-tags in the Circle-ci orb) or shall I opt for a different way of testing this?

Thanks in advance